# Fortran: 2D array taking value not assigned

Tags: arrays, fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

I am creating a 2D array `phi` and initializing it to 0. I am then going through a pair of do loops to modify some of the values of `phi`. However, some of the values are being assigned when they shouldn't be.

Specifically when I run the example below (compiling with either ifort 14 or 15) about 1/3rd of the bottom row are `-20`, when I compile with gfortran about 1/3rd of the bottom row are `-20`, and another 1/3rd are `10`.

When I uncomment the `phi(i,j) = 0.0` before the `if-elseif` statement, the value of `phi(i,j)` stays `0.0`. So it's not that the `if-elseif` is changing its value.

Does anyone know what is causing this?

As a side issue when I uncomment `close (42)`, nothing I place after it will execute. So I'm not sure if that's related.

Thank you,

John

```
program test
implicit none
real, parameter, dimension(2) :: delta = (/ 1E-7, 1E-7 /)
real,parameter,dimension(2) ::  Length = (/ 6E-6, 5E-6 /)
integer, PARAMETER, dimension(2) :: cells = Length / delta
real, dimension(cells(1), cells(2)) :: phi

REAL,parameter :: V0 = -20
REAL,parameter :: VL = 10
integer :: i,j

phi = 0.0

open(unit=42,file='ChangeValuePhi.csv',form='formatted')
do i = 0, size(phi,1)
    do j = 0, size(phi,2)
            if (j .ne. 0) then
                write(42,'(A)',Advance="NO") ","
            endif

!           phi(i,j) = 0.0
            if (j <= nint(lowerBoundary(i * delta(1)) / delta(2))) then     !If at minimum z feature
                phi(i,j) = V0
            elseif (j >= nint(upperBoundary(i * delta(1)) / delta(2))) then     !If at maximum z feature
                phi(i,j) = VL
            end if

            write(42,'(F6.2)',Advance="NO") phi(i,j)
    enddo
    write(42,*) 
enddo
!close(42)

contains

function lowerBoundary(r) result(z)
    real :: r,z
    real, parameter :: RL = 3E-6
    real, parameter :: HL = 3E-6

    if (r < RL) then
        z = HL - HL * (r / RL)
    elseif (r >= RL) then
        z = 0.0
    endif
end function lowerBoundary

function upperBoundary(r) result(z)
    real :: r,z
    real, parameter :: RU = 0.0
    real, parameter :: HU = 0.0

    if (r <= RU) then
        z = Length(2) - (HU - HU * (r / RU))
    elseif (r > RU) then
        z = Length(2) - 0.0
    end if
end function upperBoundary


end program test
```

Comment: are you not getting any runtime error with division by zero in `upperBoundary`? you are dividing by `RU` that is zero.

Comment: No because r>= 0, but you're right that I should change where the "or equal" is to avoid a division by zero error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing `phi` out of bounds.  In your loop,

```
do i = 0, size(phi,1)
    do j = 0, size(phi,2)
...
!           phi(i,j) = 0.0
            if (j <= nint(lowerBoundary(i * delta(1)) / delta(2))) then     !If at minimum z feature
                phi(i,j) = V0
            elseif (j >= nint(upperBoundary(i * delta(1)) / delta(2))) then     !If at maximum z feature
                phi(i,j) = VL
            end if
...
enddo
```

you are accessing `phi` with either `i` or `j` equal to 0.  Fortran arrays are 1-indexed unless you specifically declare the lower bound to be something else (e.g. 0).  The incorrect output you are seeing is due to the out of bounds access.

You can change the beginning of your do loop to

```
  do i = 1, size(phi,1)
     do j = 1, size(phi,2)
        if (j .ne. 1) then
           write(42,'(A)',Advance="NO") ","
        endif
```

to avoid the out of bounds access.

Comment: Okay, I've apparently been staring at my computer for to many hours. Thank you.

Comment: @user1543042 I know that feeling all too well.